# Нераспознаваемый формат базы данных

Tags: c#, mdb

При компеляции вилазит исключение "Нераспознаваемый формат базы данных"

```
 class Engine
    {
    readonly string _fname;
            readonly string[] columns;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection connection;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand Command;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader Reader;
            public Engine(string filename, params string[] columnsNames)
            {
                _fname = filename;
                columns = new string[columnsNames.Length];
                Array.Copy(columnsNames, columns, columnsNames.Length);
            }
            public Angar SelectAllTasks(string tableName) //Виберіть усі завдання
            {
                Loader();
                Angar answer;
                answer = new Angar();
                string SQL = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " ;";
                Reader = Execute(SQL);
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    Task temp;
                    temp = new Task
                    {
                        //DO IT
                        Body = Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("Body")).ToString(),
                        Header = Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("Header")).ToString(),
                        Worker = Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("Worker")).ToString(),
                        ID = Convert.ToInt64(Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("ID"))),
                        IsDone = (bool)Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("IsDone")),
                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("TargetDate")))
                    };
                    answer.Storage.Add(temp);
                }
                return answer;
            }
            public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<object> Select(string tableName,
            string columnName, string value, string comma) //Вибір елементів Перший елемент - це CellsCount
            {
                Loader();
                System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<object> answer;
                answer = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<object>();
                string SQL = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + "WHERE " + columnName + "=" + comma + value + comma + ";";
                Reader = Execute(SQL);
                answer.Add(Reader.FieldCount);
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        answer.Add(Reader[i]);
                    }
                }
                return answer;
            }
            public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<object> SelectAll(string tableName) //вибрати користувача. Перший елемент - CellsCount
            {
                Loader();
                System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<object> answer;
                answer = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<object>();
                string SQL = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + ";";
                Reader = Execute(SQL);
                answer.Add(Reader.FieldCount);
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        answer.Add(Reader[i]);
                    }
                }
                return answer;
            }
            private System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader Execute(string command)
            {
                Command = connection.CreateCommand();
                Command.CommandText = command;
                return Command.ExecuteReader();
            }
            private void Loader()
            {
                if (connection == null)
                    connection = CreateConnection();
                if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    connection.Open();
            }
            private System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection CreateConnection() //Створіть з'єднання
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection c;
                c = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + _fname + ";");
                return c;
            }
            public void InsertNewTask(Task t, string tableName)
            {
                Loader();
                string sql = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (TargetDate,Header,Body,Worker,IsDone) VALUES ('" + t.Date.ToShortDateString()
                    + "','" + t.Header.Replace("'", "`") + "','" + t.Body.Replace("'", "`") + "','" + t.Worker.Replace("'", "`") + "'," + t.IsDone.ToString() + ");";
                Execute(sql);
            }
            public void UpdateTask(Task t, string tableName)
            {
                Loader();
                string SQL = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET TargetDate='" + t.Date.ToShortDateString() +
                    "' , Header='" + t.Header.Replace("'", "`") + "' , Body='" + t.Body.Replace("'", "`")
                    + "' , Worker='" + t.Worker.Replace("'", "`")
                    + "' , IsDone=" + t.IsDone.ToString() + " WHERE ID=" + t.ID.ToString() + ";";
                Execute(SQL);
            }
            public Task SelectById(string tableName, long id)
            {
                string SQL = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE ID=" + id.ToString() + " ;";
                Reader = Execute(SQL);
                Reader.Read();
                Task temp;
                temp = new Task
                {
                    //DO IT
                    Body = Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("Body")).ToString(),
                    Header = Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("Header")).ToString(),
                    Worker = Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("Worker")).ToString(),
                    ID = Convert.ToInt64(Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("ID"))),
                    IsDone = (bool)Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("IsDone")),
                    Date = Convert.ToDateTime(Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("TargetDate")))
                };
                return temp;
            }
            public Angar SelectByDate(string tableName, DateTime dt)
            {
                Loader();
                string SQL = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE TargetDate='" + dt.ToShortDateString() + "';";
                Angar answer;
                answer = new Angar();
                Reader = Execute(SQL);
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    Task temp;
                    temp = new Task
                    {
                        //DO IT
                        Body = Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("Body")).ToString(),
                        Header = Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("Header")).ToString(),
                        Worker = Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("Worker")).ToString(),
                        ID = Convert.ToInt64(Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("ID"))),
                        IsDone = (bool)Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("IsDone")),
                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("TargetDate")))
                    };
                    answer.Storage.Add(temp);
                }
                return answer;
            }
            public void DeleteTask(string tableName, Task t)
            {
                Loader();
                string sql = "DELETE FROM " + tableName + " WHERE ID=" + t.ID.ToString() + ";";
                Execute(sql);
            }
            public void DeleteAllTask(string tableName)//Видаліть усі завдання
            {
                Loader();
                string sql = "DELETE FROM " + tableName + ";";
                Execute(sql);
            }
            public Angar SelectTask(string tableName, string columnName, string value, string comma)//Виберіть за певним стовпцем та значенням
            {
                Loader();
                string SQL = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + columnName + "=" + comma + value + comma + ";";
                Angar answer;
                answer = new Angar();
                Reader = Execute(SQL);
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    Task temp;
                    temp = new Task
                    {
                        //DO IT
                        Body = Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("Body")).ToString(),
                        Header = Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("Header")).ToString(),
                        Worker = Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("Worker")).ToString(),
                        ID = Convert.ToInt64(Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("ID"))),
                        IsDone = (bool)Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("IsDone")),
                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("TargetDate")))
                    };
                    answer.Storage.Add(temp);
                }
                return answer;
            }
        }
        public class Task
        {
            long _id;
            string _worker, _body, _header;
            DateTime _Date;
            bool _isdone;
            public long ID
            {
                get { return _id; }
                set { _id = value; }
            }
            public string Worker
            {
                get { return _worker; }
                set { _worker = value; }
            }
            public string Body
            {
                get { return _body; }
                set { _body = value; }
            }
            public string Header
            {
                get { return _header; }
                set { _header = value; }
            }
            public DateTime Date
            {
                get { return _Date; }
                set { _Date = value; }
            }
            public bool IsDone
            {
                get { return _isdone; }
                set { _isdone = value; }
            }
            public object[] ToValues()
            {
                object[] a;
                a = new object[6];
                a[0] = ID;
                a[1] = Date;
                a[2] = Header;
                a[3] = Body;
                a[4] = Worker;
                a[5] = IsDone;
                return a;
            }
        }
        class Angar
        {
            System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Task> Array;
            public Angar()
            {
                Array = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Task>();
            }
            public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Task> Storage
            {
                get { return Array; }
                set { Array = value; }
            }
            public static Angar operator +(Task obj, Angar obj2)
            {
                obj2.Storage.Add(obj);
                return obj2;
            }

        }
```

Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal.OleDbConnectionInternal(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionString, System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection)
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, object, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection)
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionPoolKey, object, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool, System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolGroup, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal, out System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal)
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal>, System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions)
    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(System.Data.Common.DbConnection, System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory)
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
    CourseMelnik.Engine.Loader() в Engine.cs
```

Comment: `Jet.OLEDB.4.0` - не пора ли перейти на `ACE.OLEDB.12.0`?

Comment: Есть же `reader.GetInt64()` или `reader.GetString()` зачем эти  `Convert.ToInt64(Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("ID")))` и `Reader.GetValue(Reader.GetOrdinal("Body")).ToString()` ?

Comment: Если вы работаете с MS Sql Server зачем вам `OLEDB`? Или вы с Access работаете? Тогда воспользуйтесь советом из коммента @Alexander Petrov